# Scraping Sports Data With Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my first-time web scraping with beautiful soup and wanted to do a little project with hockey since I am a huge fan of the sport. I am a little stuck and wondering how to retrieve the header names of the stats for each player.

Here is my current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/year/2020/seasontype/2"

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

allStats = []
players = soup.find_all('tr', attrs={'class':re.compile('row player')})
for player in players:
    stats = [stat.get_text() for stat in player.find_all('td')]
    allStats += stats
body = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"wrapper"})

print(allStats)

allColumns = []
headers = soup.find_all('tr', attrs = {'class': 'colhead'})
for col in headers:
    columns = [col.get_text() for col in headers.find_all('td')]
    allColumns += columns

print(allColumns)
```

I am currently getting an error that says "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s' for the line

```
headers = soup.find_all('tr', attrs = {'class': 'colhead'})
```

Eventually, I want to get a list of all of the Stat Names being tracked and use that as the columns in a pandas dataframe that lists each player and their corresponding stats.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If table is static did you try pd.read_html(url)  to retrieve list of tables from page with pandas as pd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your `headers` iteration that's why you're getting the error,

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

I suppose the expected result is as follows.

```
allColumns = []
headers = soup.find_all('tr', attrs = {'class': 'colhead'})
for header in headers:
    columns = [head.get_text() for head in header.find_all('td')]
    allColumns += columns
>>>
['', 'PP', 'SH', 'RK', 'PLAYER', 'TEAM', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'PTS', '+/-', 'PIM', 'PTS/G', 'SOG', 'PCT', 'GWG', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A', '', 'PP', 'SH', 'RK', 'PLAYER', 'TEAM', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'PTS', '+/-', 'PIM', 'PTS/G', 'SOG', 'PCT', 'GWG', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A', '', 'PP', 'SH', 'RK', 'PLAYER', 'TEAM', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'PTS', '+/-', 'PIM', 'PTS/G', 'SOG', 'PCT', 'GWG', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A', '', 'PP', 'SH', 'RK', 'PLAYER', 'TEAM', 'GP', 'G', 'A', 'PTS', '+/-', 'PIM', 'PTS/G', 'SOG', 'PCT', 'GWG', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as alternative, there is an espn api to get the statistics. But it's not documented as to how to pull a specicif season or season type:

`http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/statistics`

However, you can pull out player stats from the nhl.com site with their api:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd



url = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams'
jsonDataTeams = requests.get(url).json()

teamsDict = {}
for team in jsonDataTeams['teams']:
    rosterLink = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com' + team['link'] + '/roster'
    teamsDict.update({team['name']:rosterLink})
    
playersDict = {}
for team, link in teamsDict.items():
    jsonDataPlayers = requests.get(link).json()
    for player in jsonDataPlayers['roster']:
        playerLink = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com' + player['person']['link'] + '/stats'
        playersDict.update({player['person']['fullName']:playerLink})
    print ('Downloaded: %s' %team)
    

rows = []
count = 0 
tot = len(playersDict)
for player, link in playersDict.items():
    count+=1
    payload = {'stats':'statsSingleSeason',
               'season':'20192020'}
    playerStats = requests.get(link, params=payload).json()
    try:
        row = playerStats['stats'][0]['splits'][0]['stat']
        row.update({'player':player})
        rows.append(row)
        print ('%s of %s - Stats collected for: %s' %(count,tot,player))
    except:
        print ('%s of %s - No stats available for: %s' %(count,tot,player))

    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.head(20).to_string())
   timeOnIce   ot  shutouts  ties  wins  losses   saves  powerPlaySaves  shortHandedSaves  evenSaves  shortHandedShots  evenShots  powerPlayShots  savePercentage  goalAgainstAverage  games  gamesStarted  shotsAgainst  goalsAgainst timeOnIcePerGame  powerPlaySavePercentage  shortHandedSavePercentage  evenStrengthSavePercentage               player  assists  goals   pim  shots   hits  powerPlayGoals  powerPlayPoints powerPlayTimeOnIce evenTimeOnIce penaltyMinutes  faceOffPct  shotPct  gameWinningGoals  overTimeGoals  shortHandedGoals  shortHandedPoints shortHandedTimeOnIce  blocked  plusMinus  points  shifts evenTimeOnIcePerGame shortHandedTimeOnIcePerGame powerPlayTimeOnIcePerGame
0    2340:03  3.0       1.0   0.0  16.0    20.0  1186.0           132.0              26.0     1028.0              29.0     1110.0           155.0           0.917              2.7692     40          39.0        1294.0         108.0            58:30                85.161290                  89.655172                   92.612613       Corey Crawford      NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN             NaN              NaN                NaN           NaN            NaN         NaN      NaN               NaN            NaN               NaN                NaN                  NaN      NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN                  NaN                         NaN                       NaN
1    1179:36  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     69           NaN           NaN           NaN            17:05                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN         Travis Zajac     16.0    9.0  28.0   72.0   58.0             1.0              1.0              39:55        942:36             28       52.84     12.5               1.0            0.0               1.0                3.0               197:05     39.0      -12.0    25.0  1476.0                13:39                       02:51                     00:34
2    1504:25  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     68           NaN           NaN           NaN            22:07                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN          P.K. Subban     11.0    7.0  79.0  151.0   88.0             2.0              6.0             160:14       1232:41             79        0.00      4.6               3.0            0.0               0.0                0.0               111:30     90.0      -21.0    18.0  1883.0                18:07                       01:38                     02:21
3    1112:11  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     65           NaN           NaN           NaN            17:06                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN        Kyle Palmieri     20.0   25.0  41.0  155.0   74.0            11.0             18.0             206:17        891:54             41       32.43     16.1               3.0            1.0               0.0                0.0                14:00     36.0       -4.0    45.0  1374.0                13:43                       00:12                     03:10
4    1020:59  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     51           NaN           NaN           NaN            20:01                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN       Dmitry Kulikov      8.0    2.0  32.0   54.0  104.0             0.0              0.0              06:20        944:51             32        0.00      3.7               1.0            0.0               0.0                0.0                69:48     77.0       -4.0    10.0  1241.0                18:31                       01:22                     00:07
5     538:48  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     27           NaN           NaN           NaN            19:57                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN          Ryan Murray      7.0    2.0   4.0   32.0   12.0             0.0              2.0              23:15        460:25              4        0.00      6.3               0.0            0.0               0.0                0.0                55:08     50.0       -9.0     9.0   708.0                17:03                       02:02                     00:51
6    1584:26  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     69           NaN           NaN           NaN            22:57                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN       Damon Severson     23.0    8.0  52.0  114.0   81.0             3.0             10.0             137:22       1277:50             52        0.00      7.0               2.0            0.0               0.0                0.0               169:14     97.0      -20.0    31.0  1924.0                18:31                       02:27                     01:59
7     417:53  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     29           NaN           NaN           NaN            14:24                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN       Connor Carrick      5.0    1.0  17.0   25.0   27.0             0.0              0.0              02:29        402:01             17        0.00      4.0               1.0            0.0               0.0                0.0                13:23     39.0       -6.0     6.0   564.0                13:51                       00:27                     00:05
8     969:45  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     66           NaN           NaN           NaN            14:41                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN         Nikita Gusev     31.0   13.0  12.0  158.0   12.0             5.0             15.0             164:10        805:25             12       33.33      8.2               2.0            0.0               0.0                0.0                00:10      7.0      -15.0    44.0  1173.0                12:12                       00:00                     02:29
9     677:27  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     43           NaN           NaN           NaN            15:45                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN     Andreas Johnsson     13.0    8.0  14.0   78.0   43.0             4.0              5.0              86:53        581:07             14        0.00     10.3               1.0            0.0               0.0                0.0                09:27     21.0        0.0    21.0   897.0                13:30                       00:13                     02:01
10   1003:22  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     56           NaN           NaN           NaN            17:55                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN         Will Butcher     17.0    4.0   6.0   62.0   31.0             0.0              1.0              72:35        918:16              6        0.00      6.5               1.0            0.0               0.0                0.0                12:31     75.0       -8.0    21.0  1269.0                16:23                       00:13                     01:17
11    899:52  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     68           NaN           NaN           NaN            13:14                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN           Miles Wood     12.0   11.0  57.0  141.0  102.0             0.0              0.0              53:47        841:58             57        0.00      7.8               1.0            0.0               0.0                0.0                04:07     26.0      -19.0    23.0  1169.0                12:22                       00:03                     00:47
12   1057:23  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     65           NaN           NaN           NaN            16:16                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN          Pavel Zacha     24.0    8.0  14.0   97.0   62.0             3.0              8.0             106:40        818:37             14       43.27      8.2               1.0            0.0               2.0                4.0               132:06     19.0      -12.0    32.0  1343.0                12:35                       02:01                     01:38
13   2684:01  8.0       3.0   0.0  22.0    14.0  1328.0           160.0              36.0     1132.0              42.0     1225.0           185.0           0.915              2.7720     47          43.0        1452.0         124.0            57:06                86.486486                  85.714286                   92.408163  Mackenzie Blackwood      NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN             NaN              NaN                NaN           NaN            NaN         NaN      NaN               NaN            NaN               NaN                NaN                  NaN      NaN        NaN     NaN     NaN                  NaN                         NaN                       NaN
14    838:58  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     60           NaN           NaN           NaN            13:58                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN         Jesper Bratt     16.0   16.0   6.0  101.0   29.0             1.0              6.0             120:47        716:17              6       23.07     15.8               2.0            0.0               0.0                0.0                01:54     22.0       -6.0    32.0  1096.0                11:56                       00:01                     02:00
15    122:45  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     12           NaN           NaN           NaN            10:13                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN       Michael McLeod      2.0    0.0   4.0   11.0   19.0             0.0              0.0              00:12        120:51              4       50.00      0.0               0.0            0.0               0.0                0.0                01:42      6.0        4.0     2.0   158.0                10:04                       00:08                     00:01
16   1047:32  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     58           NaN           NaN           NaN            18:03                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN        Nico Hischier     22.0   14.0  12.0  123.0   48.0             2.0             10.0             155:56        838:15             12       51.73     11.4               1.0            0.0               1.0                2.0                53:21     37.0      -16.0    36.0  1278.0                14:27                       00:55                     02:41
17    967:47  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     61           NaN           NaN           NaN            15:51                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN          Jack Hughes     14.0    7.0  10.0  123.0   12.0             4.0              9.0             193:42        772:59             10       36.14      5.7               2.0            1.0               0.0                0.0                01:06     21.0      -26.0    21.0  1104.0                12:40                       00:01                     03:10
18   1523:44  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     68           NaN           NaN           NaN            22:24                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN          Ryan Pulock     25.0   10.0  14.0  163.0  110.0             3.0              8.0             120:08       1302:12             14        0.00      6.1               3.0            1.0               0.0                0.0               101:24    139.0        8.0    35.0  1788.0                19:09                       01:29                     01:46
19   1106:16  NaN       NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN             NaN               NaN        NaN               NaN        NaN             NaN             NaN                 NaN     64           NaN           NaN           NaN            17:17                      NaN                        NaN                         NaN       Johnny Boychuk      9.0    2.0  14.0   96.0  135.0             1.0              1.0              05:24        968:51             14        0.00      2.1               0.0            0.0               0.0                0.0               132:01    128.0      -11.0    11.0  1420.0                15:08                       02:03                     00:05
```

Comment: awesome, thank you for that I will try that out as well!